# Как в gtk работать с отдельными потоками?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3, gtk+

Создаю поток, который в фоновом режиме обновляет страницу(удаляет виджеты, и вставляет новые), но он работает крайне непредсказуемо - то вылетают ошибки сегментирования, то gtk аварийно останавливает программу, использовал и POSIX потоки и GLib. Погуглив я понял что gtk говно(потоконебезопасен), как мне тогда работать с потоками?

нашел статейку, но все функции устарели (компилятор ругается) и в самих доках написано что все функции GDK и GTK должны вызываться из основного потока
https://subscribe.ru/archive/comp.soft.prog.gtk/201110/07074453.html
это работает, но компилятор выдает предупреждение об устаревших функциях,  забить болт или как-то можно исправить?

Comment: "Погуглив я понял что gtk говно(потоконебезопасен)" - а разработчики десятков тысяч других приложений для gtk об этом знают?

Comment: @Sergey, в самой документации прямым текстом написано что все функции GTK должны вызываться ТОЛЬКО из основного потока с версии 3.6, также в ней написано что gtk потоконебезопасен

Comment: "gtk потоконебезопасен" - наверное, мы по разному понимаем "потокобезопасность". Например, *printf(,,,)* - сугубо НЕ поткобезопасна. Об этом тоже в прямо в доке написано. Это означает, что ЛЮБАЯ программа, использующая *printf()* Не является потокобезопасной. Много Вы видели программ на С, в которых нет ни одного вызова *printf()* ?

Всё дело в том, что в языке С (как и С++) нет примитивов для работы с потоками.  Всё делается через pthread программистом.  А это означает - всё зависит от программиста.

Comment: @Sergey, исходя из вашего ответа можно уже весь язык Си назвать "потоконебезопасным", но под потокобезопасностью я подразумеваю что вычисления производимые в созданном мной потоке не будут конфликтовать с другими.  В моем случае в созданном мной потоке невозможно выполнять функции GTK, ибо насколько я понял разработчики с версии 3.6 выпилили такую возможность, поэтому приходится использовать более старую версию и терпеть предупреждения компилятора

Comment: *можно уже весь язык Си назвать "потоконебезопасным"* - совершенно верно. Сравните с языками, к примеру, Rust или Go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Библиотека GTK не предназначена для работы с потоками и библиотека GTK корректно работает только в одном потоке, если Вы хотите работать с потоками можно воспользоватся стандартной библиотекой [pthread](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages//man7/pthreads.7.html) или библиотекой [Glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/)

Comment: Я же в вопросе написал что этими либами пользовался, сам gtk не поддерживает многопоточность, но как тогда программировать многопоточные приложения с использованием gtk?

Comment: Здесь уже вопрос к архитектуре проекта , а не технический. Зачем Вам несколько потоков?  В программе лучше создавть  один основной поток который занимается взаимодействием с пользователем. Что бы этот  основной поток никогда не зависал и всегда мог взаимодействовать с пользователем. Другие потоки выполняют дополнительные функции и если поток завис, основной поток смог это понять и сообщить пользователю.

Comment: Может я юн и неопытен, но я не понимаю как в моем проекте обойтись без доп потока. Если вкратце, мой отдельный поток работает в фоновом режиме постоянно отправляя простой мускул запрос и если вернувшееся значение  удовлетворяет моему условию, то я обновляю виджет и все данные в нем

Comment: Все корректно фоновый поток опрашивает сервер оставляет данные в памяти , основной поток смотрит эти данные и обновляет интерфейс. Зачем в фоновом процессе обновлять интерфейс , а если запрос где то подвиснет , интерфейс не обновится,  за блокируется ?  , и кто сообшит пользователю что запрос завис ?

Comment: У меня даже если запрос зависнет, то вся программа будет работать без подвисаний, просто она не получит актуальные данные вовремя.Тут, видимо уже без исходников никак,так как мы похоже немного по разному представляем как работает мой проект.

Comment: Никто не мешает в потоке не обновлять виджет , а обновить данные, а в основном потоке посмотрть данные и обновить виджет. Разработчики GTK не стали добовлять потокобезопасноть (уменьшает быстродействие и увеличивает код) поэтому не обходимо работать с GTK в одном потоке. Такая особеность библиотеки